# Should I use System.Drawing in a console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, coordinates, system.drawing

I'm making a console game in C# and a lot of the time I have to manage the position or size of an object. So I thought that I would use the `Point` and `Size` structs from `System.Drawing`. When I googled that namespace, though, there was a lot of results talking about Windows Forms, but are these structs also used for console apps? Or do people just make their own small structs for that? Just a quick question, I'd like to know what the best practices are.

Example:

```cs
using System.Drawing;

class Entity
{
    public Point Position;
    public Size Size;

    // Other entity stuff
}
```

or:

```cs
class Entity
{
    public int X, Y, Width, Height;

    // Other entity stuff
}
```

or:

```cs
class Entity
{
    public Point Position;
    public Size Size;

    // Other entity stuff
}

struct Point
{
    public int X, Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

struct Size
{
    public int Width, Height;

    public Point(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

Also, the `System.Drawing.Point` struct has a lot of stuff attached to it, so i don't know.

Comment: You can use it just fine.

Comment: There are classes inside `System.Drawing` that represent native GDI objects, which would not be suitable for use in a console application, but `Point` isn't one of them (except for the funky constructor overload that takes an `int`, I'd avoid that).

Comment: There's a lot to be said for trying stuff like this and if it works then all is good.

Comment: If you don't want it in there, make your own class? From the looks of it, you're not doing anything special anyways.

Comment: OK, i guess I'll make my own struct so that I have full control about what I'm doing